# Cache performance of pointers to adjacent memory

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, iteration

Let's assume I have a std::map of actual data, stored in a contiguous chunk of memory, that I want to iterate over while skipping a few elements. I have a function assembling a vector of pointers to elements of the map. My question is:
 **Will iterating over this list of pointers and following them cause frequent cache misses?**
For now let's assume the whole map fits in a few cache lines.

Edit: code example. Code snippet editor doesn't work on touch devices such as mine, but I will try to format in a readable fashion.

```
int main() 
{
    std::map<unsigned int, MyStruct> map;
    //Fill this map with useful data.

    std::vector<MyStruct*> ptrvec; //vector of pointers to pass around. Will not be processed right here, that's just to simplify the example code

    for(MyStruct i : map)
    {
        if(/*some condition to select structs*/) 
        {
            ptrvec.push_back(&i);
        }
    }

    for(MyStruct* i : ptrvec)
    {
        //Do some processing on MyStruct
    }
}
```

Comment: This question is very hypothetical. Measure and Profile

Comment: map of actual data? Stored in a contiguous chunk of memory?  Please explain better. Question on performance should always be answered with actual experiments. Benchmarking is the way.

Comment: I am currently not within reach of a computer, but as soon as I can, I will test performance. I'm actually asking this to find out more about the "patience" of CPU cache. Will it remember the map if I go back to iterating over the vector, or will it throw out everything, even if in a few cycles that same data is accessed again? I'm assuming the vector is in a different place in the memory, and that everything can be stuffed into at worst the L3 cache

Comment: I believe the cache is able to help you in this case as no matter where those pointers are stored, you are accessing the same memory locations in two periods of time close to each others. It does not matter if it is a map or whatever data structure you use. It is only about accessing the same memory. But again, those are only words. You need to test this on an actual computer, with an actual compiler, and an actual runtime context. Good luck.

Comment: @Davie Spataro Right. Thanks. Added a code example to help with understanding the question, but your comment is the answer I was looking for.  If you post it as an answer, I can mark it as the solution. Thank you.

Comment: Use `for (auto &i : map)`